# Yahoo Finance - get sector data for dynamic list of tickers

Tags: list, for-loop, stock, yahoo-finance, sector

I am trying to get the sectors for a list of tickers and add them to a list. I pull the list of tickers from a workbook stored on my computer which is updated at the end of each trading day, so I don't want to hard-code the tickers.

All the tickers taken from the workbook are stored in ticker_list. I use a loop to iterate through the list and retrieve the sector for each ticker:

```
import yfinance as yf
sector_list=[]

for tik in ticker_list:
    ticker=yf.Ticker(tik)
    sector=ticker.info['sector']
    sector_list.append(sector)
    
sector_list
```

This throws an error:

```
KeyError: 'sector'
```

This code works for other Yahoo Finance attributes, such as 'beta'. Anyone know why it isn't working as written above for the sector attribute?

Comment: Have you examined specifically which ticker fails, and on exactly which line? Have you examined the entire `ticker.info` object for that ticker to see whether `sector` is defined for that ticker?

Comment: OK, this seems to be the problem. I have a bunch of ETFs [RHS, RTM, RYE, RYF, RYT, VHT, VOX]  in the list but when I remove them the code works. This is weird because Yahoo Finance shows a sector for these ETFs under the Analysis tab.

Answer (score 0):

The following codes will work for you.

```
import yfinance as yf
ticker_list = ["AAPL", "GOOG", "MSFT"]

sector_list=[]

for tik in ticker_list:
    ticker=yf.Ticker(tik)
    sector=ticker.info['sector']
    sector_list.append(sector)
    
sector_list
```

Output:

```
['Technology', 'Communication Services', 'Technology']
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work individual stocks, but not for ETFs unfortunately.